# Overriding both Clicked event and its corresponding OnClicked raises compile-time error

Tags: c#

The `Derived3` causes compile-time error:

> Error CS0070  The event 'Base.Clicked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Base')

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual event EventHandler Clicked;

    public void Click()
    {
        OnClicked();
    }

    protected virtual void OnClicked()
    {
        Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Clicked
    {
        add { base.Clicked += value; }
        remove { base.Clicked -= value; }
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Clicked;

    protected override void OnClicked()
    {
        Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}


public class Derived3 : Base
{
    public override event EventHandler Clicked
    {
        add { base.Clicked += value; }
        remove { base.Clicked -= value; }
    }

    protected override void OnClicked()
    {
        Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

## Question

Why are we not allowed to override both `Clicked` event and `OnClicked` method as in `Derived3` class?